# extending php execution time

Tags: php, curl

Have tried to extend the execution time by these methods but the script keeps ending prematurely. It is basically cycling through a mysql database and doing something with each row. It should be lasting maybe five to ten minutes but stops consistently early at the same spot. I have tried the following:

```
 set_time_limit(0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2000000);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200000);
```

None of them are working. Please help!

```
    <?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
$user="5aabf73bdd2c7";
//$user = $_POST['user'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "placeprint_1";
$password = "JS313833";
$dbname = "placeprint_1";
// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2000000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200000);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ( $ch );
return $data;
}

$sql = "SELECT link, id, cookie FROM rawlinks WHERE cookie='$user' ORDER by ID desc ";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $getimagefrom=$row["link"];
    $id=$row["id"];
        $cookie=$row["cookie"];
echo $getimagefrom;
echo "<br><br>ID:".$id."<br><br>";
$htmlaa = file_get_contents_curl($getimagefrom);
$docaa = new DOMDocument();
@$docaa->loadHTML($htmlaa);
$nodesaa = $docaa->getElementsByTagName('title');
$nodesxaa = $docaa->getElementsByTagName('img');
//get and display what you need:
$titlev = $nodesaa->item(0)->nodeValue;
$metasv = $docaa->getElementsByTagName('meta');
$asv = $docaa->getElementsByTagName('img');
for ($iv = 0; $iv < $metasv->length; $iv++)
{
$metav = $metasv->item($iv);
if($metav->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $descriptionv = $metav->getAttribute('content');
if($metav->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywordsv = $metav->getAttribute('content');
if($metav->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image');
    $languagev = $metav->getAttribute('content');
}

for ($ivv = 0; $ivv < $asv->length; $ivv++)
{

  $av = $asv->item($ivv);  
echo $av->getAttribute('src');
echo "<br>";
$cvarv = $av->getAttribute('src');
echo " <img src='$cvarv' >";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "placeprint_1";
$password = "JS313833";
$dbname = "placeprint_1";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$getimagefrom = rtrim($getimagefrom, '/');

$cvarv = urlencode($cvarv);
$titlev = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $titlev);
$descriptionv = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $descriptionv);

}
    }
} 
$con->close();
echo "FINISHED!!!!";
?>
```

Comment: Are you certain that it's PHP causing the halt and not your database?

Comment: No great point. How could I determine/adjust that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php.ini try to increase the `max_execution_time` and restart apache server.

To locate where your php.ini is you can create a phpinfo.php file and insert the following:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

More informarion here: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

You can then get the location of the php.ini configuration file location when you visit the phpinfo.php on your browser.

From the code I can suggest that instead of doing an **INSERT** mysql request for every loop, you should prepare the insert values in the loop and then perform the actual mysql request only once after the loop is finished.

Another suggestion is to have `curl_close ( $ch );` before the `return` in `file_get_contents_curl()`

I have updated your code in order to be able to work in chunks instead of doing all the execution at once. I have created a table `import_progress` where we will store the last imported/executed row and fetch 20 rows for every execution:

```
/**
 * Get the last imported ID
 *
 * @param mysqli $con
 *
 * @return int
 */
function get_last_inserted_id( $con ) {
    $sql    = "SELECT imported_id
          FROM import_progress
          ORDER by ID desc
          LIMIT 1";

    $result = $con->query( $sql );
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
        //Since you are fetching in descending order
        //We need to return a very high number if we did not import anything yet
        return 999999999999999999;
    } else {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            return $row['imported_id'];
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Get the last imported ID
 *
 * @param mysqli $con
 * @param array  $ids
 *
 * @return int
 */
function insert_imported_ids( $con, $ids ) {
    $ids    = array_unique( array_filter( $ids ) );
    if ( empty( $ids ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO import_progress (imported_id) VALUES";

    //We now append the data to the mysql string
    $insert = [];
    foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
        $insert[] = "($id)";
    }
    $sql    .= implode( ',', $insert ) . ';';

    return $con->query( $sql );
}

/**
 * @param string $url
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2000000 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200000 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    $data = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    return $data;
}

$user       = "5aabf73bdd2c7";
$servername = "db";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$dbname     = "stack_overflow";
// Create connection
$con = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
// Check connection
if ( $con->connect_error ) {
    die( "Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error );
}

$last_inserted_id = get_last_inserted_id( $con );
$sql = "SELECT link, id, cookie FROM rawlinks 
        WHERE cookie='$user'
        AND ID < $last_inserted_id
        ORDER by ID desc
        LIMIT 20";

$result = $con->query( $sql );

if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
    $imported_ids = [];
    // output data of each row
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $getimagefrom = $row["link"];
        $id           = $row["id"];
        $cookie       = $row["cookie"];
        echo $getimagefrom;
        echo "<br><br>ID:" . $id . "<br><br>";
        $htmlaa = file_get_contents_curl( $getimagefrom );
        $docaa  = new DOMDocument();
        @$docaa->loadHTML( $htmlaa );
        $nodesaa  = $docaa->getElementsByTagName( 'title' );
        $nodesxaa = $docaa->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
        //get and display what you need:
        $titlev = $nodesaa->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
        $metasv = $docaa->getElementsByTagName( 'meta' );
        $asv    = $docaa->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
        for ( $iv = 0; $iv < $metasv->length; $iv ++ ) {
            $metav = $metasv->item( $iv );
            if ( $metav->getAttribute( 'name' ) == 'description' ) {
                $descriptionv = $metav->getAttribute( 'content' );
            }
            if ( $metav->getAttribute( 'name' ) == 'keywords' ) {
                $keywordsv = $metav->getAttribute( 'content' );
            }
            if ( $metav->getAttribute( 'property' ) == 'og:image' ) {
                ;
            }
            $languagev = $metav->getAttribute( 'content' );
        }

        for ( $ivv = 0; $ivv < $asv->length; $ivv ++ ) {

            $av = $asv->item( $ivv );
            echo $av->getAttribute( 'src' );
            echo "<br>";
            $cvarv = $av->getAttribute( 'src' );
            echo " <img src='$cvarv' >";
            $cvarv        = urlencode( $cvarv );
            $titlev       = preg_replace( '/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $titlev );
            $descriptionv = preg_replace( '/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $descriptionv );

        }

        $imported_ids[] = (int)$id;
    }
    insert_imported_ids($con, $imported_ids);
}
$con->close();
echo "FINISHED!!!!";
```

Comment: max_execution_time 30 comes up

Comment: It means its currently set to 30 seconds. Change that to 600 seconds in order to have a 10minute execution time

Comment: I put this in php.ini <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule> still not working.

Comment: No you dont hve to add tht in php.ini That is used in .htaccess file to manipulate php values.  You just need to open php.ini with a text editor (vim or nano etc) and change from 30 to 600 for max_execution_time . Afterwards run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: You might need to increase memory_limit too same way

Comment: for some reason I added the memory limit and execution time and it still keeps quitting early. How can I see if it is the DB causing it?

Comment: Did the values get updated on phpinfo page? Is it stopping after the same amount of time? Can you include php code in questiion?

Comment: I added the code. Here are current php.ini values max_execution_time 600 600
memory_limit 128M 128M

Comment: Thanks for the code, can you please specify from your debugging in which part of your code is it getting the execution time out error, since I see that you are echoing throughout your process.  From the code I can suggest that instead of doing an **INSERT** mysql request for everyt loop, you should prepare the insert values in the loop and then perform the actual mysql request only once after the loop is finished. Having said that I don't think that this will solve the issue but I would still suggest t. I think it you should `curl_close ( $ch );`  before the return in `file_get_contents_curl`

Comment: Will I be able to prepare a loop and perform the post if the loop size is thousands of items? I am not really sure how I would do such a thing, maybe a small sample? Also I did place this: curl_close ( $ch );
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
 and now getting this: Warning: curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/placeprint/public_html/addimages.php on line 15

Comment: I removed the mysql insert completely and it still stops after cycling through 30 or so rows.

Comment: can you update the code with what you currently have please?

Comment: I tried the `curl_close($ch);` myself as in updated answer and did not have any warnings. Also in the updated code I noticed that you are recreating the mysql connection in `for ($ivv = 0; $ivv < $asv->length; $ivv++)` loop which is unnecessary no?
Since I do not have the database I cannot replicate the issue exactly.  Can we try to increase the memory limit for the last time to `512mb` to make sure its not the culprit

Comment: I did increase the memory limit to 512.

Comment: port 3306 right? because I am getting **Connection timed out** maybe mysql allows only connections from certain ips

Comment: I can enable remote mysql but would need your ip address to do so. Still can not determine what is stopping the script early, it runs well up about 40 ids each time.

Comment: I logged in cpanel and exported your database so I can work locally and will let you know as soon as I have further details regarding the issue

Comment: I have the following configuration and managed to run through more than 300 rows but then I stopped the execution since it seems to take very long:
max_execution_time 500
max_file_uploads 20
max_input_nesting_level 64
max_input_time -1
max_input_vars 1000
memory_limit 512M

Comment: I have also updated the code in order to be able to process rows 20 at a time in order to avoid having to increase such limits.  I already created the table `import_progress` through cpanel, so basically you need to update only the code

Comment: I deleted the cpanel creds but you are more than welcome to use the server anytime you want. I appreciate your assistance. I relocated the placement of the $con and it is actually working now!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Curl doesn't make any difference. If set_time_limit doesn't work it means that a global configuration overrides it, try printing the following:

```
var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time'));
```

One time before executing `set_time_limit(0);` and also after you've done it.

This could be editable by `php.ini` but also is typically a blocked feature in free or shared hosting providers to prevent users to over-load the shared server.

Comment: this is what comes out string(2) "30" string(1) "0"

Answer (score 0):

add

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
```

at the top of the page, here 500 is number of seconds.